# Parsing nested object

Tags: apex, rest

I am trying to parse the 'events' and 'consumer' details from this payload using Apex but am getting stuck getting to the eventData.

Could explain how I would correctly retrieve those objects?

Payload

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "eventName": "service-review-created",
      "version": "1",
      "eventData": {
        "id": "53bffd360000640002975387",
        "language": "en",
        "stars": 5,
        "title": "Great service",
        "text": "Nothing other than excellent customer service.",
        "locationId": "43f51215-a1fc-4c60-b6dd-e4afb6d7b831",
        "referenceId": "ABC-123-xyz",
        "createdAt": "2017-04-20T09:34:44Z",
        "link": "https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/reviews/53bffd360000640002975387",
        "isVerified": false,
        "consumer": {
          "id": "53bffc3900006400017e5db8",
          "name": "Customer",
          "link": "https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/consumers/53bffd360000640002975387"
        },
        "tags": [
          {
            "group": "Generic",
            "value": "Tag value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Apex:

```
Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
Map<String, List<Object>> events = (Map<String, List<Object>>)params.get('events');
```

The error I get right now:

> Invalid conversion from runtime type List to
>   Map>

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is event type is not a `Map<String, List<Object>>`, it should be `List<Map<String, Object>>`. But even if you use the right data type you can not parse it in a single statement, unless it is a defined type.

So you need to go step by step. See below.

```
String jsonString = 'your json string';
Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
List<Object> events = (List<Object>)params.get('events');
for(Object eventObj: events){
    Map<String, Object> mapofObject = (Map<String, Object>)eventObj;
    // do your magic here.
}
```

If you want to deserialize this in one go, I would recommend using a defined type, basically writing a wrapper class for your JSON structure. Personally I prefer this over an untyped method that uses Objects, Lists, and Maps.

```
public class EventWrapper{
    String eventName;
    String version;
    //...
}
```

To deserialize, you can use the below statement. With this method, you can create a wrapper class for each level if required.

```
List<EventWrapper> events = (List<EventWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(s, List<EventWrapper>.class);
```